# if condition lets value slip through

Tags: javascript, if-statement, cookies, boolean

In javascript I have made a timer and when started I keep the value if the timer is started or not in a cookie . At the beginning of the file I assign that cookie to a variable "timerStarted". Now when I am loading another page it should check if the timer was started, if so start the timer so the timer keeps running after page reload. If the value of timerStarted is false it shouldn't start the timer. I tried the following things:

```
alert(timerStarted);
timerStarted = false;

if(timerStarted !== false || timerStarted !== "false" || timerStarted.valueOf() !== false)
{
    alert(timerStarted);
    startTimer();
}
```

At the start of my JS file:

```
var timerStarted = Cookies.get('timerStarted') ? Cookies.get('timerStarted') : false;
```

The problem is that if timerStarted is false it still runs the if condition. When I alert beforehand it is false, in the condition it is also false when the code: timerStarted = false; is not inserted. The timerStarted = false; was my last try to make sure it really had the false value, still it runs the if code. When I try the conditions with timerStarted === true, it does the other way around, the timer stops even though timerStarted is true.

EDIT:

```
alert(timerStarted);
if(timerStarted != false)
{
    alert(timerStarted);
    startTimer();
}
```

This code still alerts true twice and false twice while only true should be alerted twice.

Comment: Where and how do you set timerStarted? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: shouldn't it be !=, not !==

Comment: When i tried that it did the same for me

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that if timerStarted is false it still runs the if
>   condition

That is because

- you used `!==` which is `not-identical` operator,
- you are using `||` instead of `&&`, and
- no need of `timerStarted.valueOf` if it is a `string`.

try this

```
if( timerStarted != false )
{
    alert(timerStarted);
    startTimer();
}
```

Comment: Tried this also and still both alert trigger giving me either true true or false false. Even though it should only display true 2 times, false only once before the if.

Comment: Can you share the output of `typeof timerStarted`and timerStarted itself?

Comment: The output is boolean and in this case false

Comment: Apparently before the false is set on timerStarted it is of type string. Still it does not make sense that when I set it to false before the if that it still goes in the if loop

Comment: if (!timerStarted)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue. Even though I set timerStarted = false before the if, in the if it evaluated a string, I tried to do `if (Boolean(timerStarted) != false)` and that actually worked. I haven't figured out why it evaluated a string if it is set to a boolean before the if. Thanks to gurvinder372 I figured this out because of typeof